# Configuring HTMLUNIT's logging level in Play-SBT

Tags: testing, logging, playframework, sbt, htmlunit

I'm trying to run Selenium tests using Play's built-in testing framework (`TestServer`, `FakeApp`, `running()` method) and running it through SBT, but the logging level for HTMLUNIT seems to be set at debug; causing a very large stack of useless messages.

I've already tried this:

- Setting `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit=ERROR` in application.conf
- Setting `<logger name="com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit" level="ERROR"/>` in application-logger.xml
- Doing the same thing as above but in `test/resources/logback-test.xml`

None of these seem to work. Looking at the log messages, it seems that it does understand that there is a `logback-test.xml` yet it just ignores it when it comes to HTMLUNIT.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. My problem was a lack of understanding of how play loads up xml files for logback.

There are 3 files that configure logback in play: `logback.xml`, `application-logger.xml` and `application.conf`. My issue was that I was declaring the levels in logback.xml (which loads before application-logger) but those settings were being overloaded by application-logger.

Putting the log levels on application-logger fixed the issue.